# Как удалить пользователя из массива зашедших на сервер при выходе с сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js, клиент-сервер

При заходе на сервер я добавляю в массив пользователей имя зашедшего и отправляю на сторону клиента для его отображения на сайте, как мне сделать, чтобы при выходе пользователя с сервера из массива удалялось его имя, попробовал сделать так, но не вышло.

```
   socket.on('connect user', (userName) => {
        users[id++] = userName.userConnect;
        //console.log(users);
        io.emit("users", users); // событие пользователи
        io.emit('connect user', { // событие подключенние к сессии
            name: userName.userConnect,
        });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', (id) => {
        console.log(users[id]);
        delete users[id];
        console.log("a user disconnect");
    });
})
```

Заранее объявлены переменные users и id. Как узнать какой именно id покинул, чтобы отправить на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

```
const users = [
  { id: 1, username: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, username: 'John' },
  { id: 3, username: 'Kyle' }
]

socket.on('disconnect', (id) => {
  const index = users.findIndex(user => user.id === id)
  if (index > -1) users.splice(index, 1)
})
```